# Алгоритм распределения заказов

Tags: алгоритм

Необходимо придумать алгоритм распределения заказов между исполнителями при следующих условиях:

1. каждый исполнитель может взять не более n заказов,
2. заказы должны быть распределены равномерно между исполнителями,
3. у каждого заказа есть геопозиция, и необходимо, чтобы все заказы у
   одного исполнителя были максимально близки по геопозиции,
4. у каждого заказа есть время в которое он должен быть выполнен, у
   исполнителя не должно быть заказов с одинаковым временем.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать.

Comment: На реальных данных даже обычный жадный алгоритм должен дать адекватные результаты.

Comment: Посмотрите линейной программирование. В частности симплекс-метод. Но Ваша задача довльно широкая, поэтому нужно рассматривать и другие методы пространственной кластеризации. Непонятен объём данных. Если о нём что-нибудь станет известно, то можно будет советовать что-то более конкретное.

Comment: Объем данных порядка 20 заказов. Самое важное - это поиск 100% оптимального варианта.